# Removing Duplicate values from a Lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I have a lookup field in the list and it is has duplicate values.

I found the below code and tried to use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var usedNames = {};
$("select[name='Team'] > option").each(function () {
    if(usedNames[this.text]) {
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
    }
});

});
</script>
```

But this doesn't work, what extra things do I need to do?

Comment: Show some sample input/output. or screen shots

Comment: It would be best to use the enforce unique values setting on your lookup column in your list so you don't get duplicates. This code is only going to "fix" it on the display, not resolve your actual problems.

Comment: I want to do it for EditForm.aspx page...and also applying enforce unique values doesnt work

Comment: `select[name='Team']` is that correct? check it inspecting *DOM* from browser

Comment: If you enable force unique values, you then have to go back and clean up the duplicate items. You will have a clean list, no duplicates, and no more future duplicates.

Comment: in  "select[name='Team']" Team is the column name..

Comment: use `title` instead of `name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code worked for me I have just changed the selector.

```
$("select[name='Team'] > option")
```

Instead of above

```
$("select[title='Name of your column'] > option")
```

I have replaced `name` with `title` as I did not find it in the *DOM*

[image]

Comment: While it works, it doesn't fix your underlying problem though

Comment: I agree. I have just tried to solve his js problem. **OP** should follow your suggestion for best practice @EricAlexander

Comment: Has anyone asked OP **if** the underlying List **can** be set to No Duplicates? I have come accross multiple Master-Detail use cases where we could not and needed the same remove-duplicates functionality.

Comment: It can be I guess as **OP** has said **applying enforce unique values doesnt work** in one of his comment. @DannyEngelman

Comment: My assumption by "it doesn't work" was that he didn't clean up the list data thinking that would solve the problem, when it wouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

Your underlying problem is your relational list allows duplicate values to be inserted and gives you duplicate values when used in your forms. The fix, and not the bandaid solution, is to enable the enforce unique values on the lookup field in the lookup list and delete the duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to remove the Selected value from your dropdown

*and do not need jQuery*

```
console.clear();
var doubles=[];
var select=document.querySelectorAll("select[id^=Name]")[0];
console.log(select.childNodes);//must return a nodeList
[].slice.call(select.childNodes).forEach(function(el,n){//convert nodeList to array
    console.log(n,el,el.selected);
    var v=el.innerHTML;
    if(el.selected) {
        doubles.push(v);
    } else {
        if(doubles.indexOf(v)!==-1){
            select.removeChild(el);
        }else{
            doubles.push(v)
        }
    }
    });
console.log(doubles);
```