# Lookup column crossed threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I open the list form, others column appear but as there is more than 5000 items in one lookup column, so instead of select column it shows the message that it has crossed the threshold.

There is more than 5000 items in it, but if I remove the duplicates then I will get less then 100 items in it.

I have tried to remove the duplicate using JS but this doesn't work at all.
I have one idea that I need to create one more list to have only unique value. It would be less then 100 item and then I can populate those in lookup column here.

Is there any other approach to do this?

Comment: You can create list view which will display only those 100 items you are talking about... http://bit.ly/2ookpQZ

Comment: I think your approach i sgood enough. you can have those unique values in seperate list and then make lookup of that list instead.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162793/removing-duplicate-values-from-a-lookup-field